# WebView in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

We are created a WebSites and want to add in native IOS App. We created a Mac Server and connected to the Visual Studio. Now we want to add a website to Web View. We add a Web View in Main.Storyboard form. and Code File is written on ViewControler.CS Form which is given below but when we debug this code then showing blank on emulator please help anyone.

```
 public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            vwDisplay = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
            View.AddSubview(vwDisplay); string url = "http://google.com";
            vwDisplay.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
```

Comment: UIWebView has several events that will fire on completion, error, etc - have you tried adding handlers for these events?

Comment: no sir we don't have add any handler.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you add handlers for those events - possibly there is an error that you are not seeing because you don't have the handler wired up

Comment: I am add a handler but not showing any error.

Comment: if your Storyboard has a webview, why are you also declaring it in your code-behind?

Comment: webView not declaring in Code behind but when not working then checked google where showing declared in google. then we add it

Comment: not declared, but instantiating it and adding it to the view.  You should not need to do that if it is already in the Storyboard.  Try commenting out the first two lines

Comment: In your viewdidLoad method, write  base.ViewDidLoad();
 as first line.  Move all code below this.

Comment: Mr. Darshan we have all ready base.ViewDidLoad() write in first line. then issue exists.

Comment: The UIWebview won't display incorrectly formatted URL's you need it to be the following https :// www.google.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Update your plist file by adding the below code.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Add `UIWebView` as webVeiew directly from designer and give it bounds of full screen.
And use the below code in `viewDidLoad`.

```
webVeiew.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("http://www.google.com")));
```